# Hybris: ERROR: Solr home directory <directory> contain solr.xml

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

By running my hybris server I ran into this Problem. No mentions so far on the web, any Ideas what could cause that and how to solve it?

```
ERROR: Solr home directory C:\Projects\Beiselen\hybris\config\solr\instances\default must contain solr.xml

Mar 16, 2020 12:19:05 PM de.hybris.platform.solr.controller.commands.StartSolrServersCommand apply
SEVERE: Failed to start Solr server for instance [name: default, hostname: localhost, port: 8983, mode: STANDALONE]
de.hybris.platform.solr.controller.SolrControllerException: Failed to start Solr server for instance [name: default, hostname: localhost, port: 8983, mode: STANDALONE]
        at de.hybris.platform.solr.controller.commands.StartSolrServerCommand.startSolrServer(StartSolrServerCommand.java:144)
        at de.hybris.platform.solr.controller.commands.StartSolrServerCommand.executeCommand(StartSolrServerCommand.java:115)
```

Comment: 1) take backup fo the current config and then delete it. 
2) run `ant all` and follow the instructions, Hybris will generate config folder again
3) From the backup config folder, restore your project-specific files `local.properteis`, `localextensions.xml` etc
4) run `ant clean all`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you mess up with the config folder.

1. take the backup of the current config folder
2. delete the current config folder
3. run `ant all` and follow the instructions, Hybris will generate config folder again
4. From the backup config folder, restore your project-specific files like `local.properteis`, `localextensions.xml` etc
5. run `ant clean all`

Now you are good to go